# Why is &nbsp; sent from textarea counted as two letters?

Tags: php, html

```
header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

$space = "( )";
$test_string = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $space);

if($_POST["submit"] === "yes")
{
    var_dump($space); echo md5($space);
    echo"<br>";
    var_dump($_POST["box1"]); echo md5($_POST["box1"]);
    echo"<br>";
    var_dump($test_string); echo md5($test_string);
    echo"<br>";
}

$echo = "<form method='post'>".
"<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='yes'>".
"<textarea name='box1'>".$test_string."</textarea><input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>".
"</form>";
echo"$echo";
```

If I click the SUBMIT button in the above code, I will get the following output:

```
string(3) "( )" 847f697fc150ec24253d12927fe41b75
string(4) "( )" 63679d6d8c5ac6713be008a28ee19616
string(8) "(&nbsp;)" 742fcb328936485cdd13530f39c11bc6
```

A whitespace character is calculated as a single character and output to `string(3)`.

and `&nbsp;` is calculated as 6 characters and output to `string(8)`.

by the way, **the `&nbsp;` sent from textarea** is calculated as two characters and output to `string(4)`. Even if I put `md5()` on this value, it prints a value different from the case of `string(3)`.

at first, I presume it is an encoding problem, and I've erased `header()` part, but the problem still occurs.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&nbsp;` HTML entity is interpreted by the browser's HTML parser and turned into the actual U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE Unicode character. That is then sent to the server encoded in UTF-8 as the bytes `C2 A0`. One character, two bytes.

Comment: Does it mean that whitespace is represented by two characters `C2` and `A0` in utf-8 environment? then, how can I replace `&nbsp; whitespace` with `normal whitespace`? @deceze♦

Comment: There is the abstract notion of a NO-BREAK SPACE character. That character can be expressed as `&nbsp;` in HTML, or as `C2 A0` in UTF-8. NO-BREAK SPACE is *a* whitespace character, a rather special one. There are other whitespace characters, like the normal space `20`. So, I'm not sure what you mean by "normal whitespace" exactly here.

Comment: Normal whitespace means a one-character space. In other words, var_dump on this whitespace should result in `string(1)`. @deceze♦

Comment: You're not going to get a single character from `&nbsp;` under any circumstances in UTF-8. Either it's 6 characters when sent as HTML entity, or 2 bytes when sent as UTF-8. If you expect a single byte/character space character, use a space character (U+0020), not NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0).

Comment: (Aside, in the ISO-8859-1 encoding the byte `A0` represents a non-breaking space; that would be one way to get what you expect. But I feel that's missing the point.)

Comment: I understand that NO-BREAK SPACE and whitespace are not the same.
If so, can I use `U+0020` like this?
`$space = "(&#0020;)";`
`$test_string = str_replace("&#0020;", "&nbsp;", $space);`

Comment: I don't know what you expect as a result of that. You're replacing a normal space with a NO-BREAK SPACE, then you're puzzled why it doesn't come back as a normal space…?!

Comment: All I want is just `$_POST["box1"]` appearing as a one-space space like `$space`. (While maintaining the `&nbsp;` method) In other words, I would like string(1) to be dumped when `&nbsp; in textarea` is POSTed, Not string(2).

Comment: And precisely that makes no sense. U+0020 (SPACE) is one character, one byte. The HTML entity `&nbsp;`, in whatever character encoding, is 6 characters and at least 6 bytes. U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE) is one character encoded as 2 bytes in UTF-8 (more or fewer in other encodings). You're trying to have your cake and eat it too; you can't have a character that's multiple bytes long by any reckoning appear as `string(1)`.

Comment: You're not going to get that from a "dumb" var_dump. If you really need the correct character counts, you will need to use a charset aware count function like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: What he said… are you aware of the difference between bytes and characters and that PHP only denotes *bytes* in its `var_dump` output…?

Comment: Okay. I'll read more about the difference between `U+0020` and `U+00A0`. I understand that the situation that satisfies both at the same time does not make sense. I also understand that NO-BREAK SPACE is treated as two characters in utf-8. Thank you very much for the friendly explanation. (I know the difference between bytes and characters.) @deceze♦

Comment: @Saturn No, not two *characters*, but **two bytes**. Try this: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @deceze♦ You're right. The comment above is my mistake(two characters → two bytes). The value of string() by var_dump() means 'number of **bytes**'. var_dump() outputs `string(3)` when I enter ★.

Answer (score 0):

The no-break-space is a non-ASCII character. Some Unicode implementations can use multiple bytes for one character, allowing them to use charsets far larger than the single-byte only ASCII. It's these bytes that are being counted, as it takes the code for NBSP is two characters long in UTF-8.

When you are comparing the MD5 hash of no-break-space with a regular space, of course you get a different results - they are not the same character!

See the UTF-8 encoding here, notice there are two characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings

Comment: "Unicode characters" don't start with any "control character". Non-ASCII Unicode code points encoded in, say, UTF-8 will consist of multiple bytes, the first bits of which will be "control bits".

Comment: Removed the offending sentence. Hows that?

Comment: Better, though I'd nitpick that "Unicode" has nothing to do with bytes at all; specific specifications within the overarching Unicode standard do (e.g. UTF-\*), and they each differ.

Comment: Nitpick#2 "code for NBSP is two characters long": Character is a loose term. U+00A0 is an assigned Unicode codepoint so it _can be_ called a character. Encodings transform a codepoint to one or more code units. Code units are integers of a size determined by the encoding. Those integers can be put into a byte array with a byte ordering. Code units in UTF-8 are one byte each (so byte ordering is not applicable). There are 2 UTF-8 code units for NBSP, therefore 2 bytes. HTML uses Unicode. Whether there are other character sets, such as ASCII, that have any of the same characters isn't relevant.